# Google App Engine database check if row exists by field

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Using `Google App Engine` with `python` and their database, and trying to simply see if a given row already exists.

```
    result = db.GqlQuery(
        "SELECT phone WHERE phone = :1", self.request.get('phone'))

    if result is not None:
        self.response.status = 409
        self.response.out.write(json.dumps({
            "err": self.request.get('phone') + " is already subscribed."
        }))
        return
```

This does not seem to work, even though there is no row with a given phone number. Is `result` always not `None`?

Comment: try `self.response.out.write(repr(result))` and post the result here

Comment: it might be also that self.request.get('phone') returns empty string

Comment: @fabrizioM true, printing out results should help spot that

Comment: If you want to establish is there are any matches use a keys_only query and count().  This will be faster.  Than iterating.  Have a read of the docs on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

`result` is an instance of `GqlQuery`, and will never be `None`. You're going to have to do something like iterate over it to see if you get results.